# iOS Developer Certificate appears as "Untitled"

Tags: ios, certificate

As shown in the attachment the iOS Development Certificate shows up as Untitled. Can't seem to figure out where this comes from.[image: Untitled Development Certificate]

Any idea on how to fix this ?

This is just OCD and doesn't break anything but still can't stop trying to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out.

When the development certificate is created by first generating the CSR from the Macbook and then creating the certificate from apple development portal by uploading this certificate then it would be marked as Untitled.

However, if you generate the development certificate directly from xcode (if you are a team member) by clicking on the + icon and selecting the development certificate then it would be displayed with the machine hostname.

Comment: Thanks, how do I remove the "untitled" though. It still sits there in "Manage Certificates" of XCODE, with no delete button. In Keychain, I did not find something when searching for "untitled".